# Is there impossible to quickly convert json string to lua config?

Tags: php, lua

Im trying to convert json string to lua config file, is there has a quickly way to convert it. This is my json string.

```
{
   "Config":{
      "1":{
         "id":195,
         "level":[
            239,
            239
         ],
         "item":[
            {
               "id":2,
               "type":0,
               "count":666
            }
         ],
         "gold":[
            {
               "id":0,
               "type":0,
               "count":604171500
            }
         ]
      },
     ...
}
```

Convert into lua config:

```
Config={
[1] = {
    id = 1,
    level = {45,45},
    item = {{type=0,id=2,count=666}},
    gold = {{type=0,id=0,count=1728045}},
},
...
}
```

I'm tried the code below but it returns the wrong format.
What's going wrong?

```
function duyet($mang, $hide = false) {
  if (is_array($mang)) {     
    foreach($mang as $key => $value) { 

      if (is_array($mang[$key])) {

        if (is_numeric($key)) {

          if (count($mang) > 4) {
            echo '['.$key.']={';
          } else {
            echo "{";
          }

        } else {
          echo $key.'={';
        }

        duyet($mang[$key], false);

        if ($i = count($mang)) {
          echo '},';
        }

      } else {

        if (is_numeric($key)) {

          if (count($mang) > 4) {
            echo '['.$key.'] = ';
          } else {
            echo $value.',';
          }

        } else {
          echo $key.'='.$value.',';
        }

      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What output do you get and how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: When checking `if (count($mang) > 4) {` you are checking the current function data, you should be checking the loop data - `if (count($value) > 3) {`